# Divs centered using bootstrap css and grid system all media sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to keep my divs always in the center of the screen using the bootstrap grid. I have it looking right until I get to size 991, how do I adjust this to always stay in the center of the screen no matter what size it goes down to using the bootstrap grid system?

http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/2162/

```
<!--=== Content ===-->
        <div class="container content-md">

            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                <p class="text-center margin-bottom-20"><strong>You must accept the terms of usage of this website before you can continue. Click on the "I Agree" button to continue or the "I Do Not Agree" button to close this window.</strong></p>
            </div>

            <div class="row margin-bottom-100">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="service-block service-block-u">
                        <p>Under F.S. 668.6076, e-mail addresses are public records. If you do not want your e-mail address released in response to a public-records request, do not send electronic mail to this entity. Instead, contact this office by phone or in writing. The accuracy of the information provided on this website is not guaranteed for legal purposes. Changes occur daily to the content. To obtain the most current information, please contact the Manatee County Tax Collector's office. All online payment transactions are final, and cannot be reversed, cancelled, post-dated or refunded. Copyright ©2002-2016 Manatee County Tax Collector's Office. All rights reserved</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">I Agree</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">I Do Not Agree</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                <p class="text-center"><strong>THIS INFORMATION IS BELIEVED TO BE CORRECT BUT IS SUBJECT TO CHANGE AND NOT WARRANTED</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--=== End Content ===-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in your mark-up---
For a layout to be responsive for  medium screen sizes you need to use `class="col-md-8 col-offset-md-2"`

you are having problem for screen sizes >= 991 because you don't have proper responsive classes for small devices.

according to defination bootstrap grid system as follows so for a proper rsponsive page-- you have to use `class= "col-lg-* col-md-* col-sm-* col-xs-*"`

> Extra small devices Phones (<768px) - .col-xs-
>
> Small devices Tablets (≥768px) - .col-sm-
>
> Medium devices Desktops (≥992px) - .col-md-
>
> Large devices Desktops (≥1200px) - .col-lg-

**Working example**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
            
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
            <div class="container content-md">
          
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <p class="text-center margin-bottom-20"><strong>You must accept the terms of usage of this website before you can continue. Click on the "I Agree" button to continue or the "I Do Not Agree" button to close this window.</strong></p>
      </div>
            
          <div class="row margin-bottom-100">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <div class="service-block service-block-u">
            <p>Under F.S. 668.6076, e-mail addresses are public records. If you do not want your e-mail address released in response to a public-records request, do not send electronic mail to this entity. Instead, contact this office by phone or in writing. The accuracy of the information provided on this website is not guaranteed for legal purposes. Changes occur daily to the content. To obtain the most current information, please contact the Manatee County Tax Collector's office. All online payment transactions are final, and cannot be reversed, cancelled, post-dated or refunded. Copyright ©2002-2016 Manatee County Tax Collector's Office. All rights reserved</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">I Agree</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">I Do Not Agree</button>
                    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <p class="text-center"><strong>THIS INFORMATION IS BELIEVED TO BE CORRECT BUT IS SUBJECT TO CHANGE AND NOT WARRANTED</strong></p>
      </div>
        </div>
    <!--=== End Content ===-->
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have a big gap for big screens so i use content-md on the container do you know how i close in the gap when as the size goes down?

Comment: what do you mean by big gap..can you explain a bit.

Comment: the content-md drops the spacing of the content for the next div further down the page but when the screen size gets smaller content-sm looks better

Comment: Try using content-sm only

Answer (score 0):

[**Update Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/cnsvnc/dJDHd/2164/)

use `.service-block.service-block-u` `text-align:center`

you can change `col-sm-8` to `col-sm-12`

Comment: this just makes it the full width of the screen